# Why is it that the first day of the current month being displayed is 08/03/2021 instead of 08/01/2021?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to add a filter to list orders placed month to date. The function below handles other filters like year to date. I added an else if statement in the function to set the date range as month to date. The only issue is with the start date appearing as 08/03/2021 instead of 08/01/2021(First day of August). Please help find what is causing this. Thanks.

```
function set_date_range(date_range_value) {
    // Set the date range depending on the passed value.
    // Get today's date as the End date. Note that we can't get the Local date, but we need to get the PST date.
    var today_date_value = document.search_form.today_date.value;
    var Month = today_date_value.substr(0,2);
    var Day = today_date_value.substr(3,2);
    var Year = today_date_value.substr(6,4);
    var end_date = new Date(Year, Month - 1, Day, 0, 0, 0);
    var MilliSeconds = 86400000;
    // following 3 variables are to calculate ytd 
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    var dayOfYear = Math.floor( (now-start) / MilliSeconds);

    if (date_range_value == "1week") {
        MilliSeconds *= 7;
    } else if (date_range_value == "30days") {
        MilliSeconds *= 30;
    } else if (date_range_value == "365days") {
        MilliSeconds *= 365;
    } else if (date_range_value == "mtd") {
        var now = new Date();
        var start_date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1); // 1 of current Month.
        var dayOfMonth = Math.floor( (now-start_date) / MilliSeconds);
        MilliSeconds *= parseInt(dayOfMonth-1);
    } else if (date_range_value == "ytd") {
        var start_date = new Date(Year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); // Jan 1 of current year
        MilliSeconds *= parseInt(dayOfYear-1);
    }
    
    if (date_range_value == "fromstart") {
        var start_date = new Date(2006, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0);     // Hardcoded date to 5/1/2006
    } else {
        // Start date should be incremented by 1 day as we have the dates as inclusive.
        var start_date_as_number = end_date.getTime() - MilliSeconds + 86400000;
        var start_date = new Date(start_date_as_number);
    }

    document.search_form.from_date.value = format_date(start_date);
    document.search_form.to_date.value = format_date(end_date);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does this give me?

Comment: Hi.. [Skillnte jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdfseu5k) Please check the fiddle..it is coming as Aug, 01... I can't find the issue... [image for referance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRqBv.jpg)

Comment: @HimanshuBansal, yes, it is coming right in the fiddle. Not sure why I get a different day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today_date_value = "19/08/201";
var Month = today_date_value.substr(0,2);
var Day = today_date_value.substr(3,2);
var Year = today_date_value.substr(6,4);
var end_date = new Date(Year, Month - 1, Day, 0, 0, 0);
var MilliSeconds = 86400000;
// following 3 variables are to calculate ytd 
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var dayOfYear = Math.floor( (now-start) / MilliSeconds);
var date_range_value = "mtd";

if (date_range_value == "1week") {
    MilliSeconds *= 7;
} else if (date_range_value == "30days") {
    MilliSeconds *= 30;
} else if (date_range_value == "365days") {
    MilliSeconds *= 365;
} else if (date_range_value == "mtd") {
    var now = new Date();
    var start_date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1); // 1 of current Month.
    console.log(start_date.toString());
    var dayOfMonth = Math.floor( (now-start_date) / MilliSeconds);
    MilliSeconds *= parseInt(dayOfMonth-1);
} else if (date_range_value == "ytd") {
    var start_date = new Date(Year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); // Jan 1 of current year
    MilliSeconds *= parseInt(dayOfYear-1);
}

if (date_range_value == "fromstart") {
    var start_date = new Date(2006, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0);     // Hardcoded date to 5/1/2006
} else {
    // Start date should be incremented by 1 day as we have the dates as inclusive.
    var start_date_as_number = end_date.getTime() - MilliSeconds + 86400000;
    var start_date = new Date(start_date_as_number);
}

console.log(start_date);
console.log(end_date);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdfseu5k) Please check the fiddle..it is coming as Aug, 01..... [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRqBv.jpg)

Comment: Hi, the problem is caused by `format_date(start_date)` . Your earlier comment can be converted into an answer that I can accept if you like.

Comment: @CodeForGood updated to comment ^^ Thanks !!

Comment: Humanshu, I hope you are keeping well. I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147

Comment: @CodeForGood Hi, I can help with that but the link is expired. If I could get some references.. I'll be happy to help you with that ^^... Feel free to reach out.